# Regular expression for multiple emails in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, email-validation

In my application I validate emails; but we can give more than one email address separated with a semicolon (";").  How can I write the validation expression?

My emails look like this:

```
"sasidhar@yahoo.com;suryasasidhar@gmail.com;srinivas@gmail.com "
```

How can I write a regular expression for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try:

`\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*([,;]\s*\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)*`

This is from [RegexLib.com](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=735)

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [basic email regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and then apply as follows:

```
<email regex>(;<email regex>)*
```

Comment: hi Mr. Lgnaci Vazquez-Abrams can u give me the regular expression, thanks for response

Comment: @Surya, email regex is provied within VS.NET's regex validator option.

Comment: Thank you mr. Lgnaci Vazxquex abrams thanks for response and link